# Is there a way to find a column with values in forward sequence in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm filtering records having the values in forward sequence. ex: My query is `select col from mytable where col like '123456789' or col like '987654321'`. Is there any logical way to accomplish this ?

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to do. Maybe more examples would help.

Comment: Your method works, if you are looking for strings.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a sequence of any length of digits in a string (well, up to 10 characters), you can use `like`:

```
where '0123456789' like concat('%', col, '%') or
      '9876543210' like concat('%', col, '%')
```

I added `0` for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

**It seems you want to look for strings where every character is in sequence with the one before it according to the ASCII/Unicode tables.**

You can split the strings into single characters using a tally function or CTE, then check that no character is out of order.

> I use [Itzik Ben-Gan's famous cross-join tally](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/01/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-1). Add or remove cross-joins depending on how large your strings are.

```sql
WITH
    L0 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c 
            FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),
                        (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS D(c) ), --up to 16
    L1 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B ),   -- up to 256
    L2 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B )    -- up to 65536

SELECT *
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(
    CASE WHEN ASCII(LEFT(t.YourString, 1)) <
              ASCII(RIGHT(t.YourString, 1))
      THEN 1 ELSE -1 END
) ) v(IsAscending)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP (LEN(t.YourString) - 1)
          rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
        FROM L2
    ) Nums
    WHERE rn > 1 AND
        ASCII(SUBSTRING(t.YourString, rn + 1, 1)) -
        ASCII(SUBSTRING(t.YourString, rn, 1))
      <> v.IsAscending
)
```

Change `ASCII` to `UNICODE` if you are using `nvarchar`.